The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine
I have taken over a project that uses the vfpoledb.exe package.
I am running Windows 11 with Visual Studio 2019. The vfpoledb.exe was installed under an admin account.
The solution builds as expected with no errors but when I try to run the application, I get the following error message:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine.

   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
:
:

I have tried to run the project under x86 but same error appears.

You need to target platform x86 and it works, provided VFPOLEDB is installed. I have been using it for years. (I am not the one who downvoted and I have no idea why was it downvoted)

You are saying vfpoledb.exe was installed, but it is not an exe. Are you sure it is installed?

You need to be sure you have installed it and you are targeting x86. Easiest way to test it is to use LinqPad. LinqPad has a free version and version 5 is 32 bits (do not try with AnyCPU version).
Download LinqPad 5, select C# program as language, copy and paste the following code, press F4 to add System.Data.OleDb to "additional namespace imports" (using System.Data.OleDb).
void Main()
{
    var testcode = @"
create cursor test (id i, myName c(10))
local ix
for ix=1 to 10
   insert into test (id, myName) values (m.ix, 'Name #'+ltrim(str(m.ix)))
endfor
SetResultSet('test')
    ";

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    string strCon = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=d:\temp\Data";
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "ExecScript";
        OleDbParameter parm = cmd.CreateParameter();
        parm.OleDbType = OleDbType.Char;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

        parm.Value = testcode;

        tbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();
    }
    tbl.Dump();
}

Above code should run without errors and you would get a table of 10 rows. It means that VFPOLEDB is installed and you are not targeting x86 in your project. Otherwise double check that you have VFPOLEDB installed.

Code works in LinqPad but when I try it VS2022 with exact code, I am getting the same error message 'The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine.'. I set the Platform on the Debug to x86, rebuilt the project but it still fails.

@wakthar, I believe you are not setting target platform to x86.

Apologies, I was mistaken, it does work using Linqpad 5. I'm getting the same error message:  InvalidOperationException
The 'VFPOLEDB' provider is not registered on the local machine.

If it is working in Linqpad5 but not VS, then you are not setting platform to x86. Why don't you simply put a 64 bits check temporarily.

Ah damn, I did it again, I should have said IT DOES NOT work using Linqpad 5, getting same error message.

@wakthar, then it means you didn't install VFPOLEDB driver.
